# Converting form tag to simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I go about converting this form tag below into a form_for?

```
<%= form_tag(contact_email_path, :method => 'post') do %>

    <%= label_tag "Your email" %>


    <%= text_field_tag "sender", @sender, :autofocus => true %>
        <%= label_tag "Subject" %>

    <%= text_field_tag "subject", @subject %>

    <%= label_tag "Message" %>

    <%= text_area_tag "message", @message %>

 <%= submit_tag "Send Email" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` is a helper for creating forms which create or edit a resource.

If you have a resource here that you would like to create in your database, you would use this method. What it looks like you're doing here is not creating a resource, but sending an email. If that is the case, then a `form_tag` is probably a better option.

If you are, however, trying to create a new resource in the database (i.e. an new instance of `ContactEmail` or some other class), then you could do it like this:

```
<%= form_for @contact_email do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :sender, "Your email" %>
  <%= f.text_field :sender, :autofocus => true %>

  <%= f.label :subject %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>

  <%= f.label :message %>
  <%= f.text_area :message %>

  <%= f.submit "Send Email" %>
<% end %>
```

This assumes that `@contact_email` is an object that has the methods `sender`, `subject` and `message` and that you have `resources :contact_email` in your routes file.

Comment: You beat someone to the punch. +1